# getting IllegalStateException when playing new song

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an audio player app it works fine once but when i send a new arraylist it just crash .I am not able to understand what error i am doing 
this is the error log.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=beatbox.neelay.dummybeat.PlayNewAudio flg=0x10 } in unnion.neelay.beatbox.MediaService$6@a324e56
                                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:893)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                       at android.media.MediaPlayer._setAudioStreamType(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.media.MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(MediaPlayer.java:1732)
                                                                       at unnion.neelay.beatbox.MediaService.initMediaPlayer(MediaService.java:408)
                                                                       at unnion.neelay.beatbox.MediaService.access$1500(MediaService.java:52)
                                                                       at unnion.neelay.beatbox.MediaService$6.onReceive(MediaService.java:904)
                                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:883)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

can someone guide me how to solve.
this is the method it is indicating

```
private void initMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();//new MediaPlayer instance

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    //Reset so that the MediaPlayer is not pointing to another data source



    StorageUtil active = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
    active.storeActiveIndex(audioIndex);


    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        // Set the data source to the mediaFile location
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activeAudio.getFile_uri());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }


    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    messagesent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid calling setAudioStreamType in playing state. Don't forget to release MediaPlayer.

```
private void initMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();//new MediaPlayer instance

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    //Reset so that the MediaPlayer is not pointing to another data source

    StorageUtil active = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
    active.storeActiveIndex(audioIndex);

    try {
        // Set the data source to the mediaFile location
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activeAudio.getFile_uri());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }

    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    messagesent();
}
```